# Can't ssh to ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Hello I am getting permission denied on the ec2 free tier when trying to ssh into my newly created ec2 instance, I have search the forums and tried the solutions provided to no avail. I would be extremely grateful for any help. Here is what I have Done

First Edited ~/.bashrc with the following

```
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=$HOME/ec2/pk-4JGFV4LMAHPSI2RLN46Z2U5DSQ7F3IUO.pem
export EC2_CERT=$HOME/ec2/cert-4JGFV4LMAHPSI2RLN46Z2U5DSQ7F3IUO.pem
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/
```

Then

```
source ~/.bashrc
ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair > ~/ec2/smitchell.pem
```

Then I created the instance via the web gui and I then try to ssh in via
    ssh -v -i /home/smitchell/ec2/smitchell.pem root@ec2-50-17-66-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com

The command results in the following

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-50-17-66-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com [50.17.66.200] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/smitchell/ec2/smitchell.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-50-17-66-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/smitchell/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: smitchell.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/smitchell/ec2/smitchell.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Once again thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Did you upload your public key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the EC2 instance? What's the result of `ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ? `sshd` is _very_ picky about files having group-write (and maybe group-read?) access, even if you're the only member of the group.

Comment: I did not upload my ssh key to the instance, How do I do that??
Also the out put of 'code' ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'code' is

drwxr-xr-x 67 smitchell smitchell 24576 2011-05-31 20:17 /home/smitchell
drwx------  2 smitchell smitchell     8 2011-05-31 19:58 /home/smitchell/.ssh

Comment: @Mitchellsg: http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys

Comment: @Michtellsg, sorry, I should have made clear that the `ls` command needs to be run on the EC2 instance, not your local machine.

Comment: @Sarnold I have tried to add my key into the ec2 instance but I'm getting unknown command on ec2-import-key. I tried switching it to ec2-add-keypair without success (help dialog comes up). Just in case it helps I am running mint 9 on the local system, also the keypair I am trying to use to connect was generated using the EC2 web config.

Comment: @mitchellsg, ah, if the keys were generated remotely, it's probably already there. Hrm.

Comment: also I have check the ec2 web config and it does indeed show smitchell under the key pairs field in the instance menu

Comment: Try `ssh -vv`? Maybe more data...

Comment: I have solved the issue by deleting and recreating both the instance and the keypair then relaunching. Thank you sarnold for all your help, I will mark this answer as closed as soon as my 8 hour wait is up

Comment: @mitchellsg, glad it's working, but pity we couldn't sort it out. I'm curious. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to login correctly by deleting the instance and my keypair via the web config and regenerating them, once I did that I was able to login. Thanks for the help everyone